# Filter two-dimensional table to find most used product by client on large table

Tags: python, sorting, filter

I have a csv file with the following structure. I would normally use pandas to do this but I don't think it's appropriate here as I'm trying to run this on up to 100 million lines. What data structure should I use?

> Client, Product, Usage
>
> "John","Coke",3
>
> "John","Pepsi",5
>
> "Sam","Budweiser",7
>
> "Sam","Pepsi",6

I want to output a table that gives me the most used product by client, so:

> Client, Most_used_product
>
> "John","Pepsi"
>
> "Sam","Budweiser"

How can I do this?

Comment: try something before asking.

Comment: Hello Alexis, have you already managed to read in the CSV? If so, what data-structure are you using to store it in your program? Once you have a data structure there are a lot of resources for sorting online. Perhaps you could try there first and then ask when you have a more specific query. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I can read the CSV. Actually what data structure to use should be my question. I'm familiar with pandas but I'm told this doesn't work well with big data (100M lines). I've started processing this table simply as text, but I don't know how to do this specific operation as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your client products csv has no repeats like this:

"John","Coke",3

"John","Pepsi",5

"John","Coke",5

and also ignoring the headings like Client, Product and Usage. The following code should work:

```
import csv
most_used_products = dict()

with open('your_csv_filename.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    products_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for client, product, str_usage in products_reader:
        usage = int(str_usage)
        if client not in most_used_products:
            most_used_products[client] = (product, usage)
        else:
            used_product, product_usage = most_used_products[client]
            if usage > product_usage:
                 most_used_products[client] = (product, usage)

for client, product_info in most_used_products.items():
    product_name, _ = product_info
    print '"%s","%s"' % (client, product_name)
```

Comment: If the problem is sorting and not reading all of the 100 million lines and also if two lines "John","Coke",3 .. "John","Coke",5 does not mean  "John","Coke",8 (summing 3+5 for the Coke product), then this solution should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Holding 100 million entries and then sorting is a little bit tricky unless you use a database format like SQLite. [Python has an interface for SQLite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) if this is really what you want to do.

Perhaps instead of loading the whole thing into memory and sorting it you could iterate over the file, line by line, only holding the maximum entry for each person. This would cut down your memory requirements and would mean you wouldn't have to sort a very large data structure, which is computationally expensive.

Just using straightforward python it might look something like this:

```
clientDict = {}

def addToDict(client,prod,num,clientDict):
    clientDict[client] = {"num":num,"prod":prod}

with open("test.csv","r") as csvFile:
    for line in csvFile:
        (client,prod,num) = line.split(',')
        num = int(num)
        if client in clientDict:
            if clientDict[client]["num"] <= num:
                 addToDict(client,prod,num,clientDict)
        else:
            addToDict(client,prod,num,clientDict)
```

This would return a dictionary with each client as a key and there favourite product and quantity as a value. Assuming that your table doesn't have too many unique clients this is more efficient than loading the whole file into memory.

This solution also doesn't take into account what happens if a person has an entry with identical numbers (i.e John, Coke,4 and John,Pepsi,4) nor does it take into account cumulative entries (i.e John, Coke, 4 will simply replace John, Coke, 2). The program is easily modified to take into account these discrepancies.